# Removing specified text from CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, foreach

it's my first attempt at doing this and I have no idea if I'm on the right lines.

Basically I want to remove text from a CSV file that contains a specific keyword but I can't figure out how to remove the line.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var searchItem = "running";

        var lines = File.ReadLines("C://Users//Pete//Desktop//testdata.csv");

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains(searchItem))
            {
                //Remove line here?
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you like to remove whole line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way if you'd like to remove a whole line:

```
    var searchItem = "running";
    var pathToYourFile = @"C://Users//Pete//Desktop//testdata.csv";
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToYourFile);
    lines = lines.Where(line => !line.Contains(searchItem)).ToArray();
    File.WriteAllLines(pathToYourFile, lines);
```

For multiple search items:

```
    var searchItems = "running;walking;waiting;any";
    var pathToYourFile = @"..\..\items.csv";
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToYourFile);
    // split with your separator, actually is ';' character
    foreach(var searchItem in searchItems.Split(';'))
        lines = lines.Where(line =>!line.Contains(searchItem)).ToArray();

    File.WriteAllLines(pathToYourFile, lines);
```

Comment: Hi, can I then modify this to say do multiple pharases? E..g. search item = "running", "walking"

Comment: It wouldn't matter, it's just to remove multiple words at once.

Comment: Perfect thanks! One last question, how would I go about numbering. Would it just be var searchItem = 0-9 ?

Comment: yes, I modified my answer with multiple search items, check it @p.lowers2

Comment: Hi, so for example it will say in my csv "jogging":20192 and I just want to remove the numbers.

Comment: It's both, so for example my csv file on one line says "Jogging":20192 then next line "Walking":91212 etc. I just want to remove the numbers on jogging but not walking

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to remove one or a few multiple words.

```
static void sd(string[] args)
{
    string contents = File.ReadAllText("C://Users//Pete//Desktop//testdata.csv");

    string output = contents.Replace("running", string.Empty).Replace("replaceThis", string.Empty).Replace("replaceThisToo", string.Empty);
    //string output = contents.Replace("a", "b").Replace("b", "c").Replace("c", "d");
}
```

To remove multiple string, you can use this...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] removeTheseWords = { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };

    string contents = File.ReadAllText("C://Users//Pete//Desktop//testdata.csv");
    string output = string.Empty;

    foreach (string value in removeTheseWords)
    {
        output = contents.Replace(value, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace

Comment: what if OP want to remove 100 search term? Is OP need to write `.Replace` function 100 times?

Comment: @er-sho Updated. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove line just skip those lines that contain your search term

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (!line.Contains(searchItem))  //<= Notice here I added exclamation mark (!)
    {
        //Do your work when line does not contains search term
    }
    else
    {
        //Do something if line contains search term
    }
}
```

**Or** alternative is to filtered your lines that does not contains your search term before loop like

```
lines = lines.Where(line => !line.Contains(searchItem));

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    //Here are those line that does not contain search term                
}
```

If your search term contains multiple words separated with comma(`,`) then you can skip  those line by

```
lines = lines.Where(line => searchItem.Split(',').All(term => !line.Contains(term)));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using foreach and removing from lines its will through an exception called collection modified exception so go with for

```
for(int i=lines.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
 if (lines[i].Contains(searchItem))
  {
    lines.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
```